# Button Click In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with React.js. This is the line of code I have:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { map } from "lodash";

function Steps({ procedure, commandSender, index }) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  function clickHandler(command, key, index) {
    commandSender(`${command}`)
    if (isSelected((index-key))) setSelected(selected.filter(s => s !== (index-key)))
    else ([...selected, (index-key)])
  }

  function isSelected(key) {
    return selected.includes(key);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {procedure.guide &&
        map(procedure.guide, (key) => (
          <a
            key={`${index}-${key}`}
            className={`bt-blue ${isSelected(index-key) ? "active" : ""}`}
            onClick={() => clickHandler('GUIDE', key, index)}
          >
            {procedure.title}
          </a>
        ))
      }
      {procedure.success &&
        map(procedure.success, () => (
          <a
            key={`${index}-${key}`}
            className={`bt-green ${isSelected(index-key) ? "active" : ""}`}
            onClick={() => clickHandler('SUCCESS', key, index)}
          >
            {procedure.title}
          </a>
        ))
      }
    </>
  );
}

export default Steps;
```

As you can see, I map a procedure, and for each item, I create an A tag, that calls a function clickHandler. This function calls another function and a setSelected. The setSelected function says which A tag is clicked or not. The only problem is that when I click in an A tag, it doesn't get selected.

But I need just the tag I clicked to have a SELECTED effect. I think for you guys it's a very easy error to correct, but I'm really a newbie with React. Please help.

Comment: There is no difference between link's except their innerTexts. You should give them a unique key or something unique and use this to understand which one was clicked. Is that clear?

Comment: Ok, I gave then an unique Key. But how do I use this key to understand which one was clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is the data structure you are using for storing selected values. Right now, it's a plain boolean, and you are dealing with an array.

You could do the following:

First, we change the selected to an array.

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
```

Then, how can we identify each procedure in a unique way? Do they have an ID? By Title? Command? Let's suppose it's by title.

```
function clickHandler(title, command) {
    commandSender(`${command}`)

    if(selected.includes(title)) {
        setSelected(selected.filter(s => s !== title)) // we unselected our procedure
    } else {
        setSelected([...selected, title]) // we add our procedure to the selected
    }
}
```

Finally, you should change the rendering of your procedures, and remove the `useEffect`, as it's unnecessary.

```
          <a
            className={`bt-green ${selected.includes(procedure.title) ? "active" : ""}`}
            onClick={() => clickHandler(procedure.title, 'SUCCESS')}
          >
            {procedure.title}
          </a>
```

Furthermore, you could create a function to determine if your procedure is selected, so you don't have to write every time `selected.includes...` :

```
function isSelected(procedure) {
   return selected.includes(procedure);
}
```

Comment: That was very good explained. But now, all the items are selected and I cant unselect them. I used a key value, instead of the title. But I don't think thats the problem.

Comment: Making the modifications above should do the work. Can you post your modified code in your answer or create a sandbox?

Comment: These are the two functions and the useEffect: `const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{
    setSelected(selected)
  },[selected])
  function clickHandler(command, key) {
    commandSender(`${command}`)
    if (isSelected(key)) setSelected(selected.filter(s => s !== key))
    else ([...selected, key])
  }

  function isSelected(procedure) {
    return selected.includes(procedure);
  }`

Comment: Where is your `key` coming from? And you should remove the `useEffect` statement as well.

Comment: I'll edit the question, sou you can see what i've changed. Now, no tags are being selected

Comment: In the question, you can see my code. The key I'm using is kind of a pattern in the projec. They use it as index-key.

Comment: Ooh, your answer was right. I forget a setSelected. Thank you so much Ferederico!

Comment: Glad to help @afr ! Please select the answer if it was useful :)

Comment: It says here that I have to have 15 reputation and I just have 13 :(